# Override alert and confirm in Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is there a way to override `alert("")` and `confirm("")` in javascript?

I use jQuery, so if there is a way to do it in this framework, I'd appreciate it.

I'd like to do stuff like:

```
override alert(msg){
    //Show custom stuff here
}

override confirm(msg){
    //Show custom stuff here.
    return watever;
}
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Yes and no.  You can simply replace them:

```
window.alert = function(msg){
    // stuff
}
```

but you're not going to get the blocking functionality that alert and confirm give you, i.e. there will be NO way to get this code to work:

```
if(confirm('Do Something?')){
   // do stuff
}
```

You're generally better off making other functions to do similar things than you are trying to replace these.

Comment: So this means that the alert will still come up?

Comment: I'm up-voting this one myself, good point about the blocking!

Comment: @Lol coder - yes, if you replace the alert function you can still make your own alert show up (but via DOM nodes usually, not the modal alert dialog).  But the rest of the code will continue to run unlike the normal alert which blocks code execution.  What exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: @cwolves I want to have my custom modal show up instead of the browser one. For eg. I want to make a custom colorbox popup with a ok/cancel button, I'll code the events for it. Then I'll return a value depending on what was clicked.

Comment: @Lol coder - There's no real reason to try and replace window.alert/confirm if you want to do that, just make your own function that creates the popup or look at any of the 100,000 popup scripts / plugins out there.

Comment: @Lol coder - If you're trying to figure out how to get a return value of something like a confirm box, read up on async programming.  Basically, you need a callback and your code becomes something like: `function confirm(msg, cb){ .... cb('Clicked OK'); }` and `confirm('Are you sure?', function(button){ .... });`

Comment: So if I have alot of existing alert and confirm calls, I'll have to replace them?

Comment: @Lol coder - unfortunately yes, at least for confirm.  As I said, there is no way to get a new confirm function to act like the built-in one.  For alerts, you can usually just replace the function and it won't effect anything.

Answer (score 2):

Just redefine it:

```
window.alert = function(msg) { console.log(msg); }
```

Comment: lol, does every brilliant person speak like this? If I ask a friend something "oh, just do that, simple stuff". Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 1):

Just define a function named `alert` or `confirm`.

```
function alert(){}; function confirm(){};
```

However, if you need reference to the original functions then you should save references to those by assigning `var oldAlert` or just define `alert` inside of another function, so `window.alert` stays untouched.

```
(function() {
  function alert(){}; // alert inside of this scope is your custom function
})();
```

Comment: or you could replace window.alert and reference `window.constructor.prototype.alert` :P