# Overriding javascript alert/confirm using jQuery and callback functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, globalization

I am working on a globalization project where I need to update all of the JavaScript confirm and alert functions with versions that can be globalized.  I was reading through some questions asked about the subject here but couldn't find any solutions that were using callback functions.  I know that just replacing these functions with a newly defined dialog will not halt the execution of the script.  Callback functions are necessary but I am having some trouble with the implementation.

Below is a block of javascript/jQuery code that I have been working with

```
PromptForExit = function () {
$(document).ready(function () {
        //new confirm
        $dialog_confirm = $('<div></div>').dialog({
            resizable: false,
            height: 100,
            modal: true,
            autoOpen: false,
            buttons: {
                "Ok - Configurable": function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                    return true;
                },
                "Cancel - Configurable": function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                    return false;
                }
            }
        });
        //new alert
        $dialog_alert = $('<div></div>').dialog({
            resizable: false,
            height: 140,
            modal: true,
            autoOpen: false,
            buttons: {
                okVal: function () {
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }
        });
        //override alert
        window.alert = function (msg) {
            $dialog_alert.html(msg).dialog('open');
        };
        //override confirm
        window.confirm = function (msg) {
            $dialog_confirm.html(msg).dialog('open');
        };
    });

    //alert testing
    var anAlert = alert("jQuery alert");
    alert(EmptyFunc(anAlert));
    anAlert = alert("jQuery alert2");
    alert(EmptyFunc(anAlert));

    //confirm testing
    var resp = confirm("jQuery confirm");
    confirm(TempFunc(resp));
    resp = confirm("jQuery confirm 2");
    confirm(TempFunc(resp));
};

TempFunc = function (response) {
    if (response) {
        //take action if user choose OK
    }
    else {
        //different flow if they choose cancel
    }
};

EmptyFunc = function (anAlert) {
    return true;
};
```

Whats happening now is only the very last gets shown, "jQuery confirm 2", but none of the others.  I imagine this is happening because my callback functions aren't setup properly but I have also noticed that anAlert and resp are always undefined after setting them to a confirm or alert.  Appreciate the help.

Comment: Note that you will not be able to replicate the behavior of the *real* "alert()" and "confirm()" in that the browser will not "wait" for your replacements to be responded to by the user.  Thus, code that expects "alert()" and "confirm()" to work normally will be broken.

Comment: See the accepted answer here: [Override alert and confirm in Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5560367/override-alert-and-confirm-in-javascript). As @Pointy said, the blocking behavior will not be replicated.

Answer (score 0):

Introduce a queue of messages. Catch the `close` event; if the queue is empty, do nothing. If it isn't, call a function to pop off the next message and display the appropriate dialog. `alert`/`confirm` should stuff a message along with its type into the queue, then call the above function if no dialog is shown at the moment.